# Meaning of the sentence "drag you out by the balls"

Tags: meaning

I noticed a sentence in the book "The Witcher: Season of Storm" p.13 :

> ... or if a rebellious rabble comes to **drag you out by the balls**, dethrone you and hang you forthwith from a dry branch

Could anyone please explain to me what it means?

Comment: If you look up the meaning of 'drag' and the vulgar sense of 'balls', specifically in the expression 'by the balls', it is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @Alberto Why not elucidate that into a proper answer?

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco - Because it doesn't answer the question, it tells the OP how to answer it himself. Which we prefer for basic research questions - we want to encourage people to look in a dictionary rather than ask us to look in a dictionary for them.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I did search for the meaning of it but completely in wrong way, so ashamed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up the meaning of 'drag' and the vulgar sense of 'balls', specifically in the expression 'by the balls', it is pretty self-explanatory:

> **drag**
>
> 1. to pull or be pulled with force, esp along the ground or other surface

---

> **balls**
>
> 1. (Anatomy) the testicles
> 2. **by the balls** so as to be rendered powerless

Of course, "drag you out by the balls" doesn't have to mean literally that. It could be a [figure of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech) in which the vulgarity of the expression places [emphasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profanity#Types_by_purpose) on the meaning.

---

*drag. (n.d.) Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014). Retrieved August 28 2019 from https://www.thefreedictionary.com/drag*

*balls. (n.d.) Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014). Retrieved August 28 2019 from https://www.thefreedictionary.com/balls*

Comment: Hello, Alberto. It's considered better practice on ELU _not_ to do leg-work that OP should themself have done and included.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, that's what I pointed out in my comment above. However, I looked at the directions on the [Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) page and I can't see explicitly explained that this type of question is discouraged. And even if the OP had done the leg-work, doesn't this belong in ELL?

Comment: OK, maybe [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) should be more easily accessible.